# Optionally retrieve related items in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have these models:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # Other attributes

class Booking(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
    departure_date = models.DateField()
```

Serializers:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ('id','name')

class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('id',
                  'arrival_date',
                  'departure_date',
                  'house')
```

As you can see, bookings are associated to houses.

Users can request information about a house through "/house/:houseId", and bookings through "/booking/:bookingId".

I'd like to return all bookings related to a house when a user requests "/house/bookings", but these should NOT be returned when simply requesting "/house/bookings" as this is a relatively expensive operation and not usually needed.

I know how to make them be returned with the house, but how to make this optional. How do I do that?

Comment: What's the difference between the two uris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it makes more sense (to me at least) to have your endpoint for bookings for a given house exist at `/house/:houseId/bookings/` since the namespace at `/house/bookings/` will already be looking for an ID.

You can also serialize the relationship between a House and Booking to display bookings for a house at the house detail endpoint. Something like:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bookings = BookingSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ('id','name', 'bookings',)
```

But if you want another endpoint, just create a view that takes the `BookingSerializer` and filters the queryset by the House ID in the kwargs:

(Again, assuming your endpoint is `/house/<house_id>/bookings/`)

```
class BookingsForHouseListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Bookings.objects.filter(house__id=self.kwargs['house_id'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of the ListAPIView, still a bit of a beginner with Django.

Comment: Is it also possible to use the HouseSerializer you proposed, but not include the bookings by default? (like some parameter, include_bookings=true)

Comment: I would create a another serializer (maybe a child of `HouseSerializer`), and override `get_serializer_class` in the view. Also, check this site out for help deciding what methods and attributes are available to you: http://www.cdrf.co/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do two serializers, one to the List of houses without showing the books, and another for the individual house, showing the books.

In the views you define the list serializer for the list uri, and the individual serializer for the individual uri.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was trying with too high-level parts of the API that restricted me more than they were helping me, I needed to do some things manually.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763864/1582024 shows how to implement a hierarchy of resources.